# Jquery button value toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery. I was trying to toggle the input field when a button is clicked. I also changed the value on the button. Now when I click the input field hides and value of button changes. I want the value to restore back when the button is clicked twice.

Does that makes sense?

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#hello').toggle();
    $('#submit').val("I don't love you");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hello" type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="love you"></button>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the solution, but you are using <input> and </button> on the submit input

Comment: @freedomn-m "button is clicked twice." what does that mean??

Comment: People, it is just a typo on the #submit element. Open with input and close with button

Comment: @ChandraShekhar click the button - wait - click the button.  It's clicked twice.  It's a standard show/hide functionality where you want to show/hide an input when clicking on a button, but updating the button caption.

Comment: @freedomn-m , got it .

Comment: Thanks! Everyone for the help here! I am just trying to learn  jquery concepts. Your comments really helps to see how many option we have to go for a single problem. I would be glad if you could also help me with resources which can help a beginner get hold of the jquery....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set data attributes with the 2 values you want to display and check the current value against one of them and toggle based on whether it matches or not.

```html
  <input id="hello" type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input id="submit" type="button" data-default="love you" data-alt="i dont love you" value="love you"></button>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $submit = $("#submit"),
          def = $submit.data('default'),
          alt = $submit.data('alt');
      $submit.on("click", function() {
        $("#hello").toggle();
        ($submit.val() == def) ? $submit.val(alt) : $submit.val(def); 
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Michael.. Is it just jquery .. or some other framework...find it a bit different. Never saw this concept of using data default/alt. but it is interesting.

Comment: @SukhpreetSinghAlang it isn't jquery or any framework. It's just simple HTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes You can access the data attributes that are in your HTML with CSS and Javascript (jquery is just a javascript library - isn't necessary, but makes it easier). This is definitely a better approach than hard coding your text in the javascript, like the answer you chose.

Comment: Thanks for the info on this. Its just that I tried that answer first. And I really did not knew about the data approach. But I understand now. It is cool. Thanks again!

Comment: @SukhpreetSinghAlang cool you're welcome. Just in general, and I'm not encouraging you to change your answer or anything, but you should choose the answer that is the best solution to your problem. Not necessarily the first. Just whichever solves your problem best. And a second consideration would be which solution is objectively the best - meaning, when people find this post in the future, the "best" answer that would work for most people might be considered so that it's at the top when people find this looking for help with a problem similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:visible` to determine if the item is currently shown or not.  As you're using toggle, you can do this immediately with:

```
$("#hello").is(":visible") ? "text on visible" : "text on hidden"
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#hello').toggle();
    $('#submit').val($('#hello').is(":visible") ? "I love you again" : "I don't love you");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hello" type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="love you"></button>
```

Comment: Lovely... Freedom.. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

a quick check of the the value of the text in the button will do the trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){
$('#hello').toggle();
    var submitButton = $('#submit');
    if(submitButton.val() === 'I dont love you'){
      submitButton.val('love you');
    } else {
      submitButton.val('I dont love you');
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hello" type="text" >
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="love you"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var clicked = false;
    var msg1 = "love you";
    var msg2 = "love you, but not".

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        clicked = !clicked;
        $('#submit').val(clicked ? msg1 : msg2);
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#submit').click(function() {
          $('#hello').toggle();
          if($('this').val() === "I don't love you"){
              $('this').val('I love you')
          } else {
              $('this').val("I don't love you");
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the documentation for .toggle() http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

.toggle() is used for displaying or hiding the matched elements, which is what its doing here.. State the expected functionality in the question

Comment: As stated clearly in the question: *"value of button changes. I want the value to restore back when the button is clicked twice."*

Comment: This is not an answer: You should ask a question in the *comments* for clarification.